# With JPA Criteria, how would I Fetch a child entity of a Joined entity without Fetching the Joined entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

On my project I'm using Groovy with Spring Data JPA's `Specification`'s to construct Hibernate queries.

I can't provide my actual queries but to illustrate my problem let's say I have Building entities, and each Building has Floors and each Floor has both Rooms and Windows.

The behavior I'm attempting to simulate is something like this native SQL query:

```
SELECT b.*, r.*
FROM building b
INNER JOIN floor f ON b.id = f.building_id
INNER JOIN window w ON f.id = w.floor_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN room r ON f.id = r.floor_id
WHERE w.id = 1;
```

I have a specification similar to the below:

```
public class MySpec implements Specification<Building> {
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(final Root<Building> root, final CriteriaQuery<?> query, final CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        final Join floorsJoin = root.join("floors");
        final Join windowsJoin = floorsJoin.join("windows");

        //I'd like to remove this line
        final Fetch floorsFetch = root.fetch("floors"); // <---

        floorsFetch.fetch("rooms", JoinType.LEFT);

        cb.equal(windowsJoin.get("id"), 1L);
    }
}
```

The line annotated above is my issue. If I leave it, the generated query looks something like this:

```
SELECT b.*, f2.*, r.*
FROM building b
INNER JOIN floor f ON b.id = f.building_id
INNER JOIN window w ON f.id = w.floor_id
INNER JOIN floor f2 ON b.id = f2.building_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN room r ON f2.id = r.floor_id
WHERE w.id = 1;
```

(notice the duplicate `INNER JOIN` of `floor` and the unneeded `f2.*` data)

If I remove it, and use the `floorsJoin` instead to fetch rooms, I get the following Hibernate error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list
```

The unneeded `f2.*` data would be OK except I can't replace the above `floorsJoin` with the `floorsFetch` because I need to join with the `windows` table (without fetching `windows`) and the `Fetch` class doesn't have a `.join` method.

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how I would accomplish what I need while still generating a single query; surely I must be missing something simple.

Any thoughts or advice you could provide would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot,
B.J.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not that simple with the JPA Criteria API. With Hibernate you could simply cast the `Fetch` to a `Join` I guess but that's not going to help you that much. I am not sure how you use the specification in this case, but if you could write the query as a whole it could look like the following

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createTupleQuery();

Root<Building> root = cq.from(Building.class);
final Join floorsJoin = root.join("floors");
final Join windowsJoin = floorsJoin.join("windows");
final Join roomsJoin = floorsJoin.join("rooms", JoinType.LEFT);

cb.equal(windowsJoin.get("id"), 1L);

cq.multiselect(
    root,
    roomsJoin
);
```